# Flutter how to stop scroll when focus TextField into CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-sliver

I'm struggling with TextField inside CustomScrollView.

In my application I have an CustomScrollView contents SliverAppBar and SliverList. Insise SliverAppBar I put TextField. When I focus TextField, SliverList auto scroll to top position then i add property showCursor: false, It stop scrolling but I want to show cursor and not scroll. How to archive this. Thank you very much!!

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            leading: Container(),
            floating: true,
            pinned: false,
            snap: true,
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(20.0),
              child: Container(),
            ), // Add this code
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 340,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
                  Center(
                    child: TextField(
                      autofocus: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        hintText: "Search",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      showCursor: true, //not show cursor
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                    color: Colors.blue[(index + 1) * 50], height: 150.0);
              },
              childCount: 10,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: open issue here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25507

Answer (score 0):

The [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25507) mentioned in the comment should be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/56413) which appears to have first landed in Flutter 1.22.0.

I've tried your sample and it's still have the same behavior.

[image]

I've tried to set the `pinned` to `true` and it's working.

```
SliverAppBar(
            leading: Container(),
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            snap: true,
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(20.0),
              child: Container(),
            ), // Add this code
```

[image]

Also, found [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60422) with the same issue. If you don't want to set the `pinned` property into `true`, you can check out the workaround suggested [in this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60422#issuecomment-651298911).

> Duplicate of
> [#25507](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25507). A
> workaround for this is to [disable
> implicitScrolling](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics/allowImplicitScrolling.html).